# Event when the first prefetch load of service worker finish

Tags: angular, events, service, load, worker

I'm working on an angular 7 app.
I can't find how to know when the first prefetch load of the service worker is finish !

I've 20Mo off data to download in order to be sure the app work OK offline.
I want to show a progression bar, how can I do

I iave try the

```
this.swUpdate.available.subscribe(() => {
```

but doesn't work !

thanks

Comment: Did you find any solution for this issue?